# What is Loglevel debug?

Tags: apache2, url-rewriting

My error.log file for my site says

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://URL/TO/REFERER
```

My question is, what is LogLevel?  I've googled it but it seems like I'm just getting things about java.  Our site is in PHP.

**Update**

I added `LogLevel debug` to the apache2.conf and restarted apache but am getting nothing different in the error logs.

Answer (score 5):

On debian, edit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and add :

```
RewriteLogLevel 3
RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
```

then reload apache :

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Access your http webpage from a browser, if the bug is still there,
you will see some info about your error in the file :

```
/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log
```

Comment: RewriteLogLevel has been completely replaced

Comment: It was for Debian Lenny :)

Comment: This doesn't work on latest versions of Apache (at least my 2.4.6 on Ubuntu). This helped me out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641618/how-to-enable-loglevel-debug-on-apache2-server