# How to enable loglevel debug on Apache2 server

Tags: debugging, apache2, error-logging

My error.log contains:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

I replaced loglevel on apache config file:

`LogLevel debug`

After restarting, I'm getting the same error message without what could be called "a backtrace". As I understand there should be those 10 lines of redirects generated by mod_rewrite regex.

After searching all over the internet I've found plenty of explanations of loglevel and mod_rewrite, but not a word of how to make loglevel debug work.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a relevant question and should not be closed. Please vote to reopen.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Edit: note that this answer is 3+ years old. For newer versions of apache, please see the answer by sp00n. Leaving this answer for users of older versions of apache.**

#### For older version apache:

For debugging mod_rewrite issues, you'll want to use RewriteLogLevel and RewriteLog:

```
RewriteLogLevel 3
RewriteLog "/usr/local/var/apache/logs/rewrite.log"
```

Comment: Should this be in a .htaccess file?

Comment: @adityamenon if you're using apache 2.3.6 or later it can go in .htaccess, otherwise it must go in the vhost definition.

Answer (score 84):

Do note that on newer Apache versions the `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel` have been removed, and in fact will now trigger an error when trying to start Apache (at least on my XAMPP installation with Apache 2.4.2):

> AH00526: Syntax error on line xx of path/to/config/file.conf:
>   Invalid command 'RewriteLog', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

Instead, you're now supposed to use the general `LogLevel` directive, with a level of `trace1` up to `trace8`. 'debug' didn't display any rewrite messages in the log for me.

Example: `LogLevel warn rewrite:trace3`

For the official documentation, [see here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging).

Of course this also means that now your rewrite logs will be written in the general error log file and you'll have to sort them out yourself.

Comment: For sorting out terminal command `grep` is incredibly helpful.

Comment: In apache 2.4 the LogLevel directive is in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` on Ubuntu. Seems obvious but it took me a second to figure that out.

Answer (score 33):

You need to use `LogLevel rewrite:trace3` to your `httpd.conf` in newer version
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging

Comment: Just remember to read the warning on that page: "Using a high trace log level for mod_rewrite will slow down your Apache HTTP Server dramatically! Use a log level higher than trace2 only for debugging!"