# Unable to get detailed logging for apache mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, logging

I'm trying to get detailed logging messages from mod_rewrite for apache 2.4.

The apache manual tells me to add this to my virtual host config:

```
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3
```

The post https://stackoverflow.com/a/17279058/671639 sugests

```
LogLevel rewrite:trace3
```

Unfortunately apache gives the same error message for both of them:

```
Syntax error on line 45 of /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:
LogLevel requires level keyword: one of emerg/alert/crit/error/warn/notice/info/debug
```

If I use `LogLevel debug`, mod_rewrite isn't logging anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error message, you're using Apache 2.2 (or earlier) which does not have trace1-trace8 LogLevels.  You'll need to use RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel on pre-2.4.

Comment: I'm using MAMP on OSX. If I go to `/Applications/MAMP/bin/apache2/bin` and call `httpd -v` I get `Apache/2.4.9`. `phpinfo()` says `Apache/2.2.25`.

Comment: I am running Apache 2.4.25 and receive the same error.