# htaccess working good on localhost, giving errors on 127.0.0.1

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

When i view my website on `localhost` it is working great. When i try to open it on my network ip `(192.68.x.x) or 127.0.0.1` im getting Error 500 Internal server error. Ive checked the apache log and this is the error :

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

I read about the same error on so and i get some htaccess examples where it should work, tried 'm all but i just keep getting the messages, and in some cases `http://localhost` also stops working. My htaccess redirects everything back to index.php from where i start my website classes.

here is my htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ index.php?param=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Could anyone point me into the right direction ? Thanks!

Comment: Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: And how do i use that?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540738/what-is-loglevel-debug

Answer (score 0):

1/ Check if you've got this rule in your hosts file : `127.0.0.1 localhost`.

2/ Check if Apache `rewrite_module` is activated.

3/ Make sure your project is in a subfolder (let's take `mysite/` as an example).

4/ Set your root htaccess (`/.htaccess`):

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

5/ Set your project htaccess (`/mysite/.htaccess`) :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mysite/
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ index.php?param=$1 [QSA,L]
```